# why cant I use client in a cog? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

here is my code in my cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

class Basic(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Logged In!")

    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("placeholder text")
    
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong!, {round(client.latency) * 1000} ms")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Basic(client))
```

I just get "unresolved reference "client" in client.latency, and the error message is "client is not defined" Why am I having this issue?

Comment: well, I don't see where you defined `client` inside that command, you're looking for `self.client`.

Comment: if I use self.client it just says the ping is 0. I don't believe that's correct. Should I be defining client in my cogs as well as my main file?

Comment: `client.latency` returns the latency in seconds (so for example `0.124`), if you round that, it will be `0` and then `0 * 1000 = 0`, so simply remove the round function.

Comment: I used * 1000 to return it in ms, it's still zero.

Comment: read my comment again @Occy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `client.latency`, use `self.client.latency`.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong!, {round(self.client.latency * 1000)} ms")
```

Comment: I just made a comment on what someone else said, am I correct? Or should it say 0 ping?

Comment: You should multiply by 1000 inside the round(). `f"Pong!, {round(self.client.latency * 1000)} ms"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.client` instead of `client`.

Your code will however always return `0`, the `latency` attribute returns the latency in milliseconds, for example: `0.124`, if you round that it will become `0` (and `0 * 1000 = 0`), you should multiply inside the round function

```py
await ctx.send(f"Pong!, {round(self.client.latency * 1000)} ms")
```